# Siddhi logical pattern AND only works for a pair of events

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have been doing some tests using WSO2 Siddhi language and I came across something that I did no fully understand. It seems like a bug/limitation but I would like to hear your opinion/recommendations.

1. Creating a chain of events using logical pattern. I tried to create a chain of 3 events connected by AND operator. Below is a very simple query I created:

   ```
   from ea=event_a[ea.status == 1] 
       and eb=event_b[eb.status == 2]
       and ec=event_c[ec.status == 3]
   select 'And_Test' as ID 
   insert into outputStream;
   ```

When I try to test it using Siddhi Try it, it shows the following error message:

> You have an error in your SiddhiQL at line 10:1, extraneous input 'and' expecting {'[', '->', '#', SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, RETURN, OUTPUT, WITHIN}

However, if I remove the third event from my query, it works fine. Below is the query that works fine:

```
from ea=event_a[ea.status == 1] 
    and eb=event_b[eb.status == 2]
select 'And_Test' as ID 
insert into outputStream;
```

It seems that I can only use AND for a pair of events. As I mentioned before, it seems like a bug/limitation. I tested it on both WSO2 CEP 4.1.0 and WSO2 CEP 4.2.0.